# How to count the number of commas (',') in a SQL table column?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table in Teradata. This table has a column named **text_column** that contains some text in format varchar(25).

I need to count the number of **','** in this column.

Comment: The so-called duplicate was not for Teradata and the answer doesn't even work in Teradata.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses the difference of lengths of strings:

```
select ( character_length(text_column) - character_length(oreplace(text_column, ',', '')) as num_columns
```